# Struts2 TypeConvertor: Forming multiple object into one

Tags: java, struts2, annotations, type-conversion

I have a requirement, where I need to convert String into double or long.

the field on which I have applied `@TypeConvertor` can also contains `String` sometimes.
As it can be seen in below snippet, `isNumber` property is true when I get a number.

is there anyway I can pass `isNumber` to Struts2 type convertor? or any other workaround for this ?

```
  Class XYZ{
       private boolean isNumber;

       private String value;


      @TypeConvertor
      public void setValue(){
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 implicitly performs a basic type conversion to a known types, `double` and `long` are these types. So, you don't need a convertor to convert these types. But if you need a custom implementation of the type converter you may try

**The action:**

```
  private Double doubleValue;

  public Double getDoubleValue() {
    return doubleValue;
  }

  @TypeConversion(converter = "com.struts.conversion.DoubleConverter")
  public void setDoubleValue(Double doubleValue) {
    this.doubleValue = doubleValue;
  }
```

**`DoubleConverter.java`:**

```
public class DoubleConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter {
  @Override
  public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] values, Class toClass) {
    Object o = null;
    try {
      o = Double.valueOf(values[0]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){}
    return o;
  }

  @Override
  public String convertToString(Map context, Object o) {
    return o==null?"":o.toString();
  }
}
```

The `@TypeConversion` annotation is to a property which type is converted. I have applied it on property of type `Double`, but you may try to apply your converter on property of type `XYZ` like

```
  @TypeConversion(converter = "com.struts.conversion.YourNumberConverter")
  public void setValue(XYZ value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
```

When converter is invoked you should get all values as `String[]` including `isNumber` and `value`.